# XLSXwriter throwing UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Requirement :

I have to write a pandas dataframe into excel after doing some specific formatting. Everything was great when I was running in OS X using 3.4 but then moved the code to a standardized 2.7.5 version in red hat. And now it is breaking with weird errors. Any solution is very much appreciated.
Code Snippet :

```
 #WRITING DIFF OUTPUT
if(len(group_of_2_df)!= 0):

  writer = xlsxwriter.Workbook("SNAPSHOT_"+ str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%S"))+ ".xlsx") # Parameterize
  xWorksheet = writer.add_worksheet("sheet_1")

  format1 = writer.add_format({'bold': False, 'font_color' : 'blue'})
  format2 = writer.add_format({'bold': False, 'font_color' : 'black'})
  format3 = writer.add_format({'bold': False, 'font_color' : 'black'})
  format4 = writer.add_format({'bold': False, 'font_color' : 'black'})

  #### Add  Header to Excel
 for idx,column in enumerate(df_header):

  xWorksheet.write(0,idx,df_header[idx])

  # rows  --> dataframe range
  #Putting Last column to first
 original_cols = group_of_2_df_update.columns.tolist()

 original_cols = original_cols[-1:] + original_cols[:-1]

 group_of_2_df_update = group_of_2_df_update[original_cols]
 for rows in range(len(group_of_2_df_update)):
 # columns ---> df_header length

for cols in range(len(df_header)):
# added utf-8 encode lets see what happens
    val = str(group_of_2_df_update.iloc[rows,cols].encode('utf8'))
    #print("value is",val)
    if(val == 'Insert'):

        format1.set_bg_color("pink")
        format1.set_font_color("black")
        #print("I am in >> loop")
        xWorksheet.write(rows+1,cols,val,format1)
        for sml_col in range(1,len(df_header)):

            #print("what is my row_col", sml_col)
            xWorksheet.write(rows+1,sml_col, str(group_of_2_df_update.iloc[rows,sml_col].encode('utf8')),format1)

        break #Break the row if pure insert
    elif (val[0:2] != '<>' ):
         format3.set_bg_color('white')
         format3.set_font_color('black')
         xWorksheet.write(rows+1,cols,val,format3)
    elif(val[0:2] == '<>'):
        #print("I am in <> loop")
       # print("inside if value now", val)
        format2.set_bg_color('yellow')
        format2.set_font_color( 'green')
        xWorksheet.write(rows+1,cols,val[2:],format2)
    elif(val[0:3] == 'Row'):
        format4.set_bg_color('red')
        format4.set_font_color('black')
        xWorksheet.write(rows+1,cols,val,format4)

if(len(group_of_2_df)!= 0):

writer.close()
```

I tried encoding it to utf-8 as the data I am trying to write will have Japanese/European character. 
Now it is failing with following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/export/home/s***/Projects/ema_avails_dummy/bin/ema_avails_version_8_20160927.py", line 457, in <module>
writer.close()
  File "/export/home/s***/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 297, in close
self._store_workbook()
  File "/export/home/s****/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 605, in _store_workbook
xml_files = packager._create_package()
  File "/export/home/s****/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 139, in _create_package
self._write_shared_strings_file()
  File "/export/home/s****/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 286, in _write_shared_strings_file
sst._assemble_xml_file()
  File "/export/home/s****/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/sharedstrings.py", line 53, in _assemble_xml_file
self._write_sst_strings()
  File "/export/home/s****/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/sharedstrings.py", line 83, in _write_sst_strings
self._write_si(string)
  File "/export/home/s****/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/sharedstrings.py", line 110, in _write_si
self._xml_si_element(string, attributes)
  File "/export/home/s****/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/xmlwriter.py", line 122, in _xml_si_element
self.fh.write("""<si><t%s>%s</t></si>""" % (attr, string))
  File "/export/home/s****/.venv/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 691, in write
return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/export/home/s****/.venv/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I will install and try with django but if in any case another import can be avoided, that solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: That is the XlsxWriter error that occurs when there are non-ascii strings that aren't encoded as utf8. However, I can see from your example that you are encoding (at least some of) your data. Maybe try to debug your program to see the string the is causing the exception and figure out where it comes from and if it is encoded properly.

Comment: @jmcnamara , why it is not failing when run on OS X  with Python 3.5 ?

Comment: @SanDan At a guess I would say it is related in some way to the `$LANG` setting on the Red Hat system. But that is just a guess. If you look at the stacktrace in a debugger you will get a better idea. Also, I don't think the Python version should have any effect but you could eliminate that variable from the equation by testing with Python 2.7 on OS X or 3.4 on Red Hat.